# How to do nested Group By with django orm?

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm

I have the following data:

```
publisher                    title
--------------------------  -----------------------------------
New Age Books                Life Without Fear
New Age Books                Life Without Fear
New Age Books                Sushi, Anyone?
Binnet & Hardley             Life Without Fear
Binnet & Hardley             The Gourmet Microwave
Binnet & Hardley             Silicon Valley
Algodata Infosystems         But Is It User Friendly?
Algodata Infosystems         But Is It User Friendly?
Algodata Infosystems         But Is It User Friendly?
```

Here is what I want to do: I want to count the number of books published by each author in a single object.
I want to get the following result:

```
{publisher: New Age Books, titles: {Life Without Fear: 2, Sushi Anyone?: 1}},
{publisher: Binnet & Hardley, titles: {The Gourmet Microwave: 1, Silicon Valley: 1, Life Without Fear: 1}},
{publisher: Algodata Infosystems, titles: {But Is It User Friendly?: 3}}
```

My solution goes something along the lines of:

```
query_set.values('publisher', 'title').annotate(count=Count('title'))
```

But it is not producing the desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can *post-process* the results of the query with the [**`groupby(…)`** function <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) of the [**`itertools`** package <sup>[Python-doc]</sup>](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html):

```
from django.db.models import Count
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

qs = query_set.values('publisher', 'title').annotate(
    count=Count('pk')
).order_by('publisher', 'title')

result = [
    {
        'publisher': p,
        'titles': {r['title']: r['count'] for r in rs }
    }
    for p, rs in groupby(qs, itemgetter('publisher'))
]
```

Comment: You my man is a legend. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Hey man. Can you please guide further? My query set contains duplicate values, which I have removed using distinct(). my query becomes

qs = query_set.values('publisher', 'title').distinct().annotate(
    count=Count('pk')
).order_by('publisher', 'title')

But it is now creating problems.

Comment: @IbrahimNoor: can you show the result of `print(qs.query)` for the original `qs` (so the one in the answer)?

Comment: Can you furthermore provide some sample data (content of the table for the `query_set` model) that does not work properly?